# Lncs template does not recognize doi

Tags: bibtex, lncs

The [guideline for proceedings authors](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svproc/guidelines/Springer_Guidelines_for_Authors_of_Proceedings.pdf) suggests to include DOIs in references, but the [LaTeX template](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) does not seem to recognize the doi fields in BibTeX files. What should I do about it?

Here is a minimal example:

test.tex

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}
Cite something~\cite{something}.

\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{splncs03}

\end{document}
```

test.bib

```
@article{something,
author = {Someone},
title = {Some title},
year = 2017,
journal = {Some journal},
doi = {doi},
}
```

Comment: You could modify the bst to add a doi field. You could take a look at the `format.url` function to see how it's defined and do something similar for `doi`. You could also look at how other bst's implement it. For example, `urlbst` looks like it'll try to display a `doi` first and if it doesn't exist it looks for other fields like `url`.

Comment: @TH. I don't think I'm supposed to change the style file...

Comment: Then you could put it in the `note` field, I guess.

Comment: Depends on the conference where you publish. Some use LNCS as format, but do not publish at Springer. When Springer is the publisher, they manually add the DOI during publication process. You send them your tex sources. It helps them if the doi is included. -- It would also be possible to work on [biblatex-lncs](https://github.com/NorwegianRockCat/biblatex-lncs).

Answer (score 1):

For those obtaining a `missing $ inserted` error when using DOIs inside a bibliography with the LLNCS style, escape the `_` of the DOIs in your bibfile by replacing them with `\_`.

That solved the problem for me.

For other useful tips, see https://hoanganhduc.github.io/blog/2019/11/20/some-tips-for-using-springer-lncs-style/